# Is there an easy characterization of functions satisfying the condition $f(x) - x f'(x) \leq 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, convex-analysis

Is there any easy way to characterize non-negative functions satisfying conditions of the form
$$f(x) - f'(x)x \leq 0$$
or the integrated version
$$2\int_a^b f(x) dx \leq f(b)b-f(a)a$$
?
From the geometric interpretation and some sample calculations, it seems to me that the above formula describes some sort of average convexity. Can this notion be made precise? Is it possible to find interesting characterizations under additional assumptions?

Comment: Why not do (assuming $f(x) \neq 0 $) $1/x \leq \frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}$ and integrate to get : $ln(x) \leq ln(f(x))$?

Comment: I think you have to write definite integrals. Your statement is equivalent to $f(x)\geq x$ which is satisfied by $f(x) = x+1$ but $f(x) - f'(x)x= 1 >0 $. But the idea is very helpful anyway! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f'(x) - \frac{1}{x}f(x)= F(x)$ for some chosen $F(x) \geq 0$. Using an integrating factor $\rho = x$ we get
$(xf)'=x F(x)$ or
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x t F(t) dt + \frac{C}{x}.$$

We see $f(x)$ will satisfy our original inequality if and only if it is of the form above where $F(t) \geq 0$. (EDIT: I'm ignoring the technicality of $x \neq 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $f(x) \neq 0$ then

$$\frac{f(x) - f'(x)x}{f(x)^2}=\left( \frac{x}{f(x)} \right)'$$

So your relation is equivalent to

$$ \left( \frac{x}{f(x)} \right)' < 0 \,.$$

This means that, for these functions, your relation is equivalent to $\frac{x}{f(x)}$ is decreasing.

Comment: The function would be decreasing if its derivative $<0$. Which would imply that $\frac{x}{f(x)}$ is decreasing

Comment: @Mathguy fixed ty